# How to share file using wifi in laptops just like bluetooth?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I want to share my files between to laptops using WiFi connection same as we do on android using apps like flashtransfer, where one laptop creates WiFi and other connects to it and start sharing of files.
How to do that on laptop.

Comment: You need to create an ad-hoc wireless network if you don't have a router. Can you please give more detail as to what laptops you want to connect together and (more importantly) what operating systems they use...

Comment: i tried on linux and changed mode to ad-hoc using iwconfig  now what next how to share my file if both laptops are running linux???????

Comment: Any particular distro (Ubuntu, CentOS etc.)?

Comment: ubuntu or fedora just guide me with steps for any one of os

Answer (score 0):

To create an ad-hoc wireless network in Ubuntu:

1. Click wifi icon at top right of screen
2. Click `Create New Wi-Fi Network`
3. Enter a network name (SSID)
4. Select your connection encryption
5. Create a passphrase
6. Click `OK`
7. On your other device connect to the new network you have just created

Comment: ok but now how to share file over wifi please guide me over sharing a file

Comment: See answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/176248/share-folders-between-two-ubuntu-12-04-machines - You should really spend more time using Google or other search engines... the question you've asked has been answered hundreds of times and a little effort from yourself wouldn't go amiss.